# Printing memory address, mapping

Tags: c, malloc, memory-address, memory-mapping

I'm trying to get arguments from the command line. and open a file for read/write, then malloc a memory to suggest the starting address to the function mmap. But it's not printing any addresses (the suggested and the kernal given address), even though it's creating the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  if(argc>=3){

    int fd;
    const char *fname=argv[1];
    const char *str=argv[2];


    if((fd=open(fname,O_CREAT|O_RDWR,0))!=-1){

       int *startaddress = malloc(strlen(str)*sizeof(char));
       mmap(startaddress, strlen(str)*sizeof(char), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,        MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

       write(fd,str,strlen(str));

       printf("File address: %d\n",fd);
       printf("Suggested file address: %p", startaddress);
       close(fd);
       free(startaddress);
     }

   }else
   printf("You didn't enter a proper number of arguments.\n");

}
```

Comment: If it's not printing any message, try adding `\n` (e.g. `printf("Suggested file address: %p\n", startaddress);` or adding `fflush(stdout);` after you print. Otherwise, check that `startaddress != NULL`. (ps: you should get the output of `mmap()` in some other pointer -- giving an address to `mmap()` is just a [_hint_](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap))

Comment: @865719 Now I get an output. Why doesn't mmap use the memory I gave it?

Comment: As [mentioned in the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) it's *a hint*: _"If addr is not NULL, then the kernel takes it as **a hint** about where to place the mapping; on Linux, **the mapping will be created at a nearby page boundary**. The address of the new mapping is returned as the result of the call."_

Comment: In other terms: the address you provided is the starting of an already _`malloc()`ated_ space, `mmap()` can't just _"use it"_. However, `mmap()` will **try** to map the data as close as possible to the chunk of memory which address you provided.

Comment: First, what is your call to `mmap()` returning?  Second, giving `mmap()` an address in the heap such as one returned from `malloc()` is a good way to destroy your heap - if your mapping succeeds at that address, it will cause the actual heap pages to be unmapped from the process address space.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `mmap` take the addresse you give it as a hint and map the memory as close as it can. To force `mmap` to allocate exactly at `startaddress` the flag MAP_FIXED must be provided.

Be warned that the manual discourage the use of this option, because it can cause memory corruption if there is already allocated memory at this addresse, or just fail.
Also, the mapping will fail if the address is not a multiple of `getpagesize`.